# Update Kubernetes job with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-jobs

I have a helm chart containing Kubernetes job but unfortunately `helm upgrade` won't work because the image name is immutable so logically I need to do a `delete` and `install` but I will loose my set `values.yaml` if they were customised in the first place.

How can I keep the values before deleting the chart and use them for new install to simulate an upgrade? I couldn't find anything in documentations or here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

First you need to get your previous values with `helm get values <release-name>`

So you could redirect the values to a file with:

```
helm get values <release-name> -o yaml > values.yaml
```

And then do a helm install again

Comment: Please read my description again

Comment: My bad man, just realized this, going to post the correct answer anyways